# How to set properties before a file upload listener is called

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces and what I want is to set a backing bean property before a fileUpload event is called so I can use said property in my event handler (in this case *handleFileUpload*):

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{modeloController.handleFileUpload}"/>
```

This is the property I wanna set

```
public class ModeloController {
    private String someParameter;

    ...

    public void setSomeParameter(String someParameter) {
        this.someParameter = someParameter;
    }

    public String getSomeParameter() {
        return someParameter;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What property you want to set ?

Comment: @Makky I edited the question adding the property to set

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori - what is the source of the property? Is it another JSF component?